# Where does Inno Setup IDE store its most recently opened file list?

Tags: inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup 5.5.5 a. When I start the Inno Setup IDE, a file list pops up. 
Where does Inno Setup store those file names?

I want to remove one of them, because it no longer exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the registry key value list stored under this key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Jordan Russell\Inno Setup\ScriptFileHistoryNew
```

Comment: I'll check this on Monday. Thanks.